# HLSCatalog apple sample app

Tags: ios, swift, http-live-streaming, fairplay

There seems to be an issue with the `HLSCatalog (HLS download and stream)` sample application.
When i try to download the Advanced Stream sample it gets stuck in endless loop trying to download the same media selection over and over.
The interesting thing is that the media selection download completes and the `urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?)` function gets called with `error nil` yet the `AVURLAsset assetCache` doesn't contain the downloaded media selection.
I didn't modify anything in the app sample app.
Anyone have any idea how to fix it? Tried it with other `HLS samples` that contain extra media selections and the same thing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After filing a Tech Support request to Apple I got a response:

> Our engineers have reviewed your request and have determined that you are experiencing a known issue for which there is no known workaround at this time.

Currently there is no fix/workaround, maybe in iOS 11.